# GWT-RPC error - subtype is not instantiable

Tags: gwt, serialization, gwt-rpc

There are following classes:

```
@Entity
public class MPolicy extends MAbstractEntity {

    private MPolicyCondition condition;

    private List<MPolicyAction> actions;

    ...

}

@Entity
public abstract class MPolicyCondition extends MAbstractEntity {

}

@Entity
public abstract class MPolicyAction extends MAbstractEntity {

    @Column(unique = true)
    protected String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Why error:

> subtype com.*.MPolicyCondition is not instantiable

appears?

If I remove abstract keyword from MPolicyCondition all is ok! But MPolicyAction class is also abstract. Why MPolicyCondition influences on bug, but MPolicyAction is no ?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a List of MPolicyAction.

And your implementation of the List, maybe a ArrayList, is instantiable.

Answer (score 2):

I found subclasses of MPolicyCondition which have not serializable members. 
So problem is solved. But compiler would can be more friendly with error explanation!